# Java Binary File Block Header

Tags: java, binaryfiles

I am trying to read a binary file that I wrote with the FileOutputStream class. The class I am using to read it is a RandomAccessFile class.

When I inspect the file in a hex editor, there seems to be about 9 extra bytes in front of my own actual data. This data seems to be ignored when using the FileInputStream class to read, however with RandomAccessFile, it is not. I have done a bit of research, and I believe this is some kind of block header. However, I can find nothing specific and would like to ask what this block header consists of.

Here is some code that showcases this problem:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String path = "C:\\Users\\Fran\\Desktop\\test.bin"; //You should change this to a valid path on your computer
    try {
        FileOutputStream fstream = new FileOutputStream(path);
        ObjectOutputStream ostream = new ObjectOutputStream(fstream);

        ostream.writeInt(300);

        ostream.close();
        fstream.close();

        FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(path);
        ObjectInputStream oIn = new ObjectInputStream(fIn);

        System.out.println(oIn.readInt());
        oIn.close();
        fIn.close();

        RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(path,"r");

        System.out.println(randomAccessFile.readInt());

        randomAccessFile.close();

    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
}
```

As you can see, RandomAccessFile does not return the same as ObjectInputStream, since it appears that ObjectInputStream ignores the mentioned block header.

Thank you.

Comment: How should we know if you don't share it with us?

Comment: It's your file. We can't see it. We didn't write the code that created it. Read your question from our point of view. *This guy is trying to read a file he wrote, doesn't show us the code that wrote it, and is asking us about some mystery bytes he can't identify from that file that he wrote and doesn't show us.*

Comment: Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),
and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: There are no block headers in Java. Only what you wrote yourself to the file.

Comment: There must be some kind of header, run the code above, and you will see that the file contains more than the 4 bytes for the integer written at the start. Only the last 4 bytes of the file contain this integer.

Comment: Excellent job with the MCVE btw. +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ObjectOutputStream` writes according to the (unimaginatively named) [Object Serialization Stream Protocol](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/specs/serialization/protocol.html).

An hexdump of the file is:

```
ac ed 00 05 77 04 00 00 01 2c
```

broken into blocks:

```
ac ed       -> magic number      java.io.ObjectStreamConstants.STREAM_MAGIC
00 05       -> version 5         java.io.ObjectStreamConstants.STREAM_VERSION
77 04       -> block of 4 bytes  java.io.ObjectStreamConstants.TC_BLOCKDATA + length
00 00 01 2c -> the int32 300
```

With `RandomAccessFile` you'll have to `skipBytes(4)` (or – arguably better – check that the file header is in fact `ac ed 00 05`) and also handle the `TC_BLOCKDATA`.

Comment: TC_BLOCKDATA is part of the *correctly* named Object Serialization Stream Protocol. Not part of `DataInput.readInt()`.

Comment: Thanks @EJP I didn't explain myself :) edited to simplify/disambiguate

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes no sense. If you're writing with an `ObjectOutputStream` you have to read with an `ObjectInputStream`.

This is Java Object Serialization at work. You can't expect to read it without using the tools provided for the purpose.

You're only using `writeInt()` and `readInt()` here, so it isn't clear why you're using serialization at all. If you're not using `writeObject()` or `readObject()` and friends, you should both be using `DataInput/OutputStream`, which doesn't have a superimposed protocol. Or he can use `DataOutputStream` and you can use `RandomAccessFile`, with care.

Comment: Why not? Where's the discrepancy?

Comment: The problem is that I am not the one producing the files, I have a partner who is doing this. Now, I would use ObjectInputStream to read, however, my code needs to rapidly be able to backtrack in the file, as I cannot hold the whole file in memory, and it is not to be read sequentially. Perhaps you would be able to suggest a class that conforms to the standards of ObjectOutputStream while filling my requirements or a way to conform to said standards?

Comment: Becasue Serialization is a protocol of its own, and you are using a raw binary technique to read it. Your file is not a 'binary file', it is a serialized stream.

Comment: There is no such thing as a serialized file that can be backtracked, or that is not to be read sequentially. If you're only using `writeInt()` and `readInt()`, or rather if you're *not* using `writeObject()` or `readObject()`, you should *both* be using `DataInput/OutputStream`, which doesn't have a superimposed protocol. Or he can use `DataOutputStream`and you can use `RandomAccessFile`, with care.